# Ever since water pressure tank replaced, the upstairs has no water when toilets flush, etc

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, well-pump

We had a leak in our pressure tank and had it replaced a few months ago. The plumber replaced some of the pipe leading up to the pressure tank, replaced the pressure gauge, and the tank itself. Since then, the upstairs has no water whenever the water downstairs is being used in any significant amount, such as when a toilet is flushed. The volume of water was never great before, but now it's non-existent.

The system is 40/60. I've upped it to 50/70 to see if it makes a difference, but there's been no change so far. I did take a swag at raising the pressure tank air pressure with a bicycle pump by 5lbs when I raised the minimum pressure. It doesn't seem to matter what the pressure is, I can have it to 70 and there's still no upstairs water when the downstairs is running.

Any help is appreciated, I'd rather not call another plumber if it's something I can adjust.

Comment: Why did you wait so long to call back the plumber to fix it? He might have dislodged rust in existing pipes when replacing the other ones.

Comment: Yes, by all means call back the plumber that did the repair.

Comment: Watch the pressure gauge while the toilet is flushed. If it drops considerably and takes a long time to recover then you have a supply issue: partially closed valve, obstruction in pipe, new pipe smaller diameter than previous pipe, ... .